# Getting Segmentation fault Core dumped error while importing robjects from rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Installed R and rpy2 manually

Installation is successful but getting the above mentioned error. Please help me out?

Outputs of some useful commands:

```
>>> import rpy2
>>> rpy2.__path__
['/home/ashish/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.8.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2']
>>> import rpy2.robjects
cannot find system Renviron
/home/ashish/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.8.2-py2.7-linux- x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:185: RRuntimeWarning: Fatal error: unable to open the base package


warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please include steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: @cel updated my question. Please help me out and thanks for the quick comment.

Comment: "manually" or using the conda installer ?

Comment: manually @lgautier

Comment: It may be important which version of R you are running.  I am noticing, at least with the Anaconda repos for OS X, that rpy2-2.8.2 is built against R 3.3.1.   A segmentation fault could be some kind of shared library version mismatch.

Answer (score 15):

If you install rpy2 via conda, and also have a system installation of R on the same machine (e.g with RStudio), the system's R installation will be used. Since this R version doesn't match the one that rpy2 needs, segmentation faults occur.

1) remove any existing system installations of R ([see here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-OS-X)). Verify that you don't have any installations of R:

```
$>which R
R not found
```

2) define `R_HOME` env variable, either in your .rc file:

```
export R_HOME=/Users/<your user>/anaconda3/envs/<env name>/lib/R
```

or dynamically in the python project:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Users/<your user>/anaconda3/envs/<env name>/lib/R'
```

Comment: This is GOLD. Solved the "Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT" issue I was getting trying to run R in Python.