# anaconda installing r with segmentation fault

Tags: anaconda

I tried to install r and rpy2 in a linux machine with anaconda so that I could use r package methods with python. However, I got this error:

```
>conda install -c r r-essentials
...
r-rcolorbrewer 1.1_2: ############################################################################################################## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Segmentation fault
```

I got the so called segmentation fault... Does Anyone know what might have happen? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you have a stand alone RStudio installation, which doesn't play nicely with R via conda. remove the standalone version, and only install rpy2 via conda.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347782/getting-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-error-while-importing-robjects-from-rpy2)